# pypyodbc - using stored procedures and storing data into a dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

So i have a stored procedure that i want to connect to and execute in python so i can export the data as a fancy table.

Here is the code im using, with the comments being code that i have tried.

```python
import plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc
import pyodbc
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#force the ODBC driver to use case-sensitive column names
pypyodbc.lowercase = True  

startdate = '2018-10-23 08:00'
enddate = '2018-10-24 12:00'

params = startdate,enddate

##Establishing a connection to SQL database

connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                'Server=LOLOL;'
                                'Database=LOL_Collection;'
                                'trusted_connection=yes;')
crsr = connection.cursor()

SQL = """

SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @start = '2018-10-23 08:00'
declare @end = '2018-10-24 12:00'
exec [dbo].[AM_SIGNAL_Histogram] @start, @end

"""


#SQL = """
#    
#exec [dbo].[AM_SIGNAL_Histogram] @start, @end
#
#"""


#result = crsr.execute(SQL)
#         
#print(result.fetchall())


df = pd.read_sql(SQL,connection)
connection.close()
```

And this is the error that i keep on getting:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='.")

Thanks for the help,
Kenneth

Comment: Full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your Python code, it's with your T-SQL. Running it directly in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS),

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @start = '2018-10-23 08:00'
declare @end = '2018-10-24 12:00'
exec [dbo].[AM_SIGNAL_Histogram] @start, @end
```

produces

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Must declare the scalar variable "@start".
```

Your `declare` statements are missing the data type. The following modification works for me:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @start varchar(50) = '2018-10-23 08:00';
declare @end varchar(50) = '2018-10-24 12:00';
exec [dbo].[AM_SIGNAL_Histogram] @start, @end;
```